# using async methods inside of array.map() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to go through an array of elements and then for each element check if a theme exists with the "findOne()" function and if not create a new theme and save it and if that theme exists just apply some changes and then save and i want it to only continue after the theme is saved but .

```
internalRoutes.post('/add_questions', (req, res) => {
    let elements = req.body
    var count = 0;
    elements.map((element) => {
        let q = new Question({ category: element.category, body: element.body, level: element.level })
        q.save().then(question => {

            Theme.findOne({ name: element.theme }).then(theme => {
                if (!theme) {
                    let new_theme = new Theme({ name: element.theme, level: element.level, questions: [], first_question: null })
                    new_theme.questions.push(question);
                    new_theme.first_question = question._id;
                    new_theme.save().then(t => {
                        console.log('new theeeeemmmmmmeeeeee')
                    })
                }
                else {
                    theme.questions.push(question);
                    theme.save().then(t => {
                        console.log('yeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrecognized');
                    })
                }
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).json("couldn't locate theme")
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).json("couldn't save question")
        })
        count++;

    })
    if (count === elements.length) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "questions added successfully" })
    }
    else res.status(500).json('error')
})
```

here's my current code , i tried many ways such as async await functions or try catch blocks but never seem to solve this does anyone know where the issue could be ?

Comment: first of all. Don't use ```map``` here. Map is a one-to-one functor. I am not seeing any transformation here but a lot of mutation. You should use ```forEach```. Two, you don't need that if statement. Just do an inline if on ```new_theme``` and eliminate the duplicate code. Last but not least, please clarify your question. I am not seeing any ```async/await``` in this code. And what do you mean by ```continue after it is saved```, continue where? what is the next thing that gets executed ?

Comment: IF you decide to go that route there are addtional steps you would need to go.  For example, your map function would need to return a Promise and ther resulting value would be a Promise[].  You would then have to do a await Promise.wait(x) essentially.   I have had to do a similar concept once because I had a list of Async functions which needed to be resolved before the app continued.  Yours is similar issue building out the async list through map instead of me creating 2-3 specific async functios.

Comment: This function is 36 lines long and indented 6 levels deep. It's a good indication for dividing that logic into a few smaller, named functions. Also: if you want to wait until all of several parallel async operations have completed, then `Promise.all` is your friend.

Comment: I think you still need to await the result from promise all, as that just resolves when all  items in the promise list resolve.

Comment: @sinanspd that code is executed for each element of the array so what i mean by continue is for the current element save and after that continue to do the same thing for the next element

Comment: also for each element i want to create a new theme for it if it doesn't exist and then save it and then go to the next element not go through all of them and then wait till all of them are saved at once because the information i need the information saved in each itiration for the next one

Answer (score 2):

You probably want some sort of `Promise.all` implementation, so you know all of the promises you fired did return.

Your example code is fairly complex, so if you could simplify it I would be able to give you a more specific approach for your case.

```js
const promisedElements = Promise.all(elements.map(async () => { ... })).then(...)
```